position absolute item breaks column
Hi I am facing problem on using column. when I set image absolute in the child column,it breaks the column. image with position absolute in item 4 breaks the column
In the origin design, it uses flex and no such problem.
original design,image at the bottom of item 4
Original code :


.column-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column-container div {
  width: 25%;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 200px;
}
<div class="column-container" style="padding: 20px 30px">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>
    4
    <div style="position: relative">
      <img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>17</div>
  <div>18</div>
  <div>19</div>
  <div>20</div>
</div>



New design :


.column-container {
  column-count: 4;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 200px;
}
<div class="column-container" style="padding: 20px 30px">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>
    4
    <div style="position: relative">
      <img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>17</div>
  <div>18</div>
  <div>19</div>
  <div>20</div>
</div>



I try to use backface-visibility: hidden and transform: translate3d(0,0,0);  but it doesnt work, may i know there is any way to let the column design looks like the original design, thanks

If you want something to be included in the flow of elements, absolute positioning is the wrong approach. Why do you need it to be absolutely positioned in the first place?

when I hover the item, I want the image will be shown next to the item

I did not understand your question fully. But still based on whatever I understood here is my solution for you...
It might or might not work. But check if this is something you needed. Hope it helps.
(Use position:relative for main parent div. and remove top right properties.)
Try hovering 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and you will understand.  (Run the Snippet Button)


body{
overflow-x:hidden;
}

.column-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column-container div {
  width: 25%;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  display:none;
}
div:hover > div.image > img{
  display:block;
}
<div class="column-container" style="padding: 20px 30px">
  <div style="position: relative">
    1
    <div class="image">
      <img style="position: absolute;" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position: relative">
    2
    <div class="image">
      <img style="position: absolute;" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position: relative">
    3
    <div class="image">
      <img style="position: absolute;" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position: relative">
    4
    <div class="image">
      <img style="position: absolute;" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position: relative">
    5
    <div class="image">
      <img style="position: absolute;" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>17</div>
  <div>18</div>
  <div>19</div>
  <div>20</div>
</div>



Hope it helps!

I want something like this, but the items should be showing in vertical order with 4 columns, so I changed my code to column-count instead of using flex. Anyway, it is quite helpful, thanks
